# Connecting to wifi disconnects the ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet

I have a model B pi connected to an old router upstairs through ethernet cable. When I connect to this router with my laptop I can SSH and VNC to the pi no problem. When I then connect the pi to another network over WiFi using my usb adapter, the ethernet connection drops thus killing my VNC and SSH connections.

I am using Raspbian Wheezy and connecting with the basic WiFi tool from the desktop. I thought this would be something fairly easy to setup but I'm not really sure what to do next.

Comment: don't your networks share same address space?

Comment: Please dont thank in the question. Use upvote to thank. I think you have a power supply issue. Once the Wifi start to connect it causes a brown out and cuts out the ethernet. You can have as many network connections as you like/need. You just more power "Scotty"!

Comment: It seems it must be a power issue, have tried booting and letting wifi connect and then plugging ethernet in. Both connect and the connections last for about a minute or 2 but then wifi drops and wpa_supplicant fails to see the device anymore. I then have to bring the IF up again but that then drops the ethernet once more. I have ordered a powered hub so will see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you are not supplying enough power to the WiFi device.  You need to either get a device that consumes less power, or use a powered USB hub instead.